# Algorithm to divide a set of symbols with constraints into minimum number of subsets

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I have a set `S={a,c,d,e,f,j,m,q,s,t}` with a constraint `C={am,cm,de,df,dm,ds,ef,em,eq,es,et,fj,fm,fs,jm,js}`. xy in C means that x and y cannot be in the same subset. I would like an algorithm to split set S into subsets Sj such that:

1.The number of Sj is minimized

2.The difference between size of each subset is as large as possible

For example in this case, both `{{q,a,c,d,j,t},{m,s},{f},{e}}` and `{{a,c,e,j},{m,s,q,t},{d},{f}}` are satisfying 1, but the first is optimal.

Coming from a computer science background, I wonder whether Mathematicians have devised an algorithm for this problem.

Comment: consider asking in: http://mathoverflow.net/ or http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm not clear on what `2` means and why that means that your first example is optimal. Is the "difference" set size? And where has `q` gone in the second example?

Comment: I think this is very closely related to the [maximal independent set problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_independent_set), which is NP-hard.

Comment: Sorry. q lost. q here is belong to {m,s,t,q}.  The difference means set size.@Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: It is an NP-hard coloring problem, but there's a literature out there on approximations/exact solutions.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, your task can be rewritten as: find the largest independent subset of vertices S' of graph G=(S, C); repeat the step for graph G'=G\S'.

It's well-known (also pointed by @tobias_k in his comment) that *largest independent set of the graph* is NP-hard problem (as it's equivalent to the famous clique-problem).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is very hard problem, and that is why. For finding minimum number of subsets, you must solve problem about minimum chromatic number of graph. This problem is generally solved by brute force.